# Oracle Application testing Suite Login Failure script issue

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle Application testing suite.I am trying to record a flow from oracle Store inventory management application.
But when there is a pop up for entering login and pasword and after entering the details the flow fails with "invalid user id and password".
But when the same is tried manually I am able to login without any issue.
What could be issue ? is there any setting issue ?
Can someone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

OATS by default encrypts (obfuscate) any password fields while recording the scripts and adds a deobfuscate just before setting any password field.

Check whether you have removed the deobfuscate() statement accidentally!